# Migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1 give Requested entity was not found

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I am migrating from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1. In updating the payload of send request I target specific devices, and it gives:

> {"error"=>{"code"=>404, "message"=>"Requested entity was not found.", "status"=>"NOT_FOUND", "details"=>[{"@type"=>"type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError", "errorCode"=>"UNREGISTERED"}]}

If i use topic instead of token, it works, and in legacy FCM apis these device token works correctly.

I was expecting to get success when send request with device tokens.

Comment: The error message indicate that you're passing an FCM token that does not exist within this project. Are you sure you're calling he FCM API on the same project from with you got the FCM token?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen- yes i am calling the FCM API on the same project from where I got the FCM token. and on legacy FCM API https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send, it was working perfectly.